# Bind existing select options to a Knockout view model

Tags: knockout.js

I'm fairly new to Knockout.js, so this might be a stupid question.

I'm reading through the Bindings documentation, and particularly the [**options** binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html). It says that when applying the binding:

> Any previous options will be removed.

Is there a way to preserve the existing options?

```
<select data-bind="options: availableOptions, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedOption">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var option = function(name, value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    };
    var viewModel = {
        availableOptions : ko.observableArray([]),
        selectedOption : ko.observable()
    };
</script>
```

Comment: No, there is no clean way to preserve them. But splitting up the available options isn't really a good idea anyway - either put the whole data in the viewmodel or in the view, don't mix that. Why do you need this "feature"? Maybe there is a better/cleaner way.

Comment: My main concern is performance: adding 100 items dynamically instead of using the ones that have already been rendered doesn't seem like a good idea. Especially in a low-power scenario like mobile.

Comment: Maybe worry about performance when it becomes an issue...  Besides, 100 items in a select box isnt exactly ideal either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on Niko's suggestion, I guess the answer is that it's best to avoid mixing declarative bindings with static data. If the view is unlikely to change, put the data in the view (option elements on the select). If it's dynamic, put the data into the KO viewmodel.

In my scenario it's the former:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedOption">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        selectedOption : ko.observable()
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What backend are you using? I would suggest putting all your existing options into a json object and filling the viewmodel with http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Backend is not an issue here, this is a purely client-side problem. (I use ASP.NET MVC3)

Comment: I wanted to know if you were using .net or ruby. Use json.net http://json.codeplex.com/ to create a json object to populate your viewmodel with. That will work the way you need for your select list.

Comment: I think Jason's point was that there's another way to do this. Serving the options up from the server keeps you from worrying about whether they are static or not, the view is dumb and just shows the options its given. The view model acts on those options the same way as well. Then if later those options need to change, your server side code is all that needs to change.